# Count in xaml not working

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

I want to get the count of notifications like this:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding notifications[notifications.Count - 1].text}">
```

But it does not work. any ideas?

notifications is an array of elements of which have a property of text. Xaml seems to allow you to use the array like syntax `notifications[ x ]` where `x` is the index of the notifications item. but the `notifications.Count - 1` does not work.

**For now I've had to do this:**

**C#**

```
public class Status
{
    public IEnumerable<Notification> notifications { get; set; }
    public Notification FirstNotification { get; set; }
}

public class Notification
{
    public string Text { get; set; }
}

IEnumerable<Status> statuses = await notificationRepository.GetAll(); // Data contract

foreach( var item in statuses )
{
    item.FirstNotification = item.notifications[ item.notifications.Last() ]; // Had to make a copy :(
}
```

**XAML:**

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding FirstNotification.text}">
```

Comment: Create a new property that represents the value? (And arrays are zero based in C# ... so that would have been one too far).

Comment: What is `notifications`? Default binding only works with public property of `TextBlock`'s `DataContext`

Comment: notifications is an array of entries all of which have a property of text.. I want to get the last entry of the notifications

Answer (score 0):

Create a new property and mention that in your xaml

property:

```
 public string notification_count
    {
        get
        {
            return notifications.Count.ToString();
        }
    }
```

and in xaml:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding notification_count}">
```

hope this works.
Thank you.

Comment: If this is to work, I need to know how to do a binding within a binding... eg. {Binding notifications[{Binding notifications.Count}]}

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `notifications` is a public property descending from `Collection` or a class implementing `ICollection` this should work:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding notifications.Count}">
```

Comment: Perhaps i'm being stupid, I should be doing ( notifications.Count - 1 ) I'll try when I get back home

Comment: I've ended up taking the obvious route which is to create a separate single notification rather than IEnumerable... It's a shame because further down I have to iterate over all of the notifications and thus I have had to copy the memory over wastefully.